# Are there any cases of Brahmana marrying a Kshatriya woman?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, ramayana, marriage, smriti

It is allowed for a Brahmana to marry a Kshatriya woman taking her as his second wife(Anuloma Vivaha)..But are there cases in Puranas and Itihasas that describe a Brahmana marrying a Kshatriya first?